# Reference Global jquery function variable within foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I want to change the value of a global jquery variable within the foreach loop every time there is a new model item.  I want to add new dates to the calendar but cant do that until I can access these functions from foreach loop.

*edit***

I over simplified my example for the question which was answered correctly by vov v.  The actual code will do a lot more than add a value as it will add data to a calendar.  I've added more code to show what it will do a little better

jquery:

```
<div id="calendar" style="width: 500px;" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var calendar = $('#calendar').glDatePicker(
        {
            showAlways: true,
            borderSize: 0,
            dowOffset: 1,
            selectableDOW: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            selectableYears: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015],
            specialDates: [
                {
                    date: new Date(2013, 0, 8),
                    data: { message: 'Meeting every day 8 of the month' },
                    repeatMonth: true
                },
                {
                    date: new Date(2013, 5, 7),
                    data: { message: 'Meeting every day 8 of the month' }
                },
            ],
            onClick: function (target, cell, date, data) {
                target.val(date.getFullYear() + ' - ' +
                            date.getMonth() + ' - ' +
                            date.getDate());

                if (data != null) {
                    alert(data.message + '\n' + date);
                }
            }
        }).glDatePicker(true);

        $('#visible').change(function () {
            var showAlways = eval($(this).val());
            calendar.options.showAlways = showAlways;

            if (!showAlways) {
                calendar.hide();
            }
            else {
                calendar.show();
            }
        });

    });
       var value = 0;

        $('#total').click(function () {
            alert(value);
        });


        function add() {

        // will eventually add new specialDates to the calendar taken from model items

        //test lines                
        //value = value + 1;
            //return value;
        }

</script>
```

razor view:

```
<input type="button" id="total"  />

@foreach (var item in Model){
    if (item.AppointmentStatus == "active")
{   
    // item display code

    @: <script type="text/javascript"> add();</script> 
}

if (item.AppointmentStatus == "history")
{
        // item display code
}
```

}

I run this and get error below as it doesnt see the other code

'0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'add' is undefined'

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to capture "a count" that you want to send down to your client then you can simply do it like this:

```
<script>
    var value = '@Model.Count';
    // the rest of you script goes here
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#total').click(function () { 
            alert(value);
        }
    });
</script>
```

So say you have 7 items in your model, then the html that will be generated is this:

```
var value = 7;
```

and when you click on that `total` element it will give you an alert with the text `7`.

Comment: Your quite right that works as I described so thanks for that.  It seems I over simplified my question for the example so Ill update that but the final product needs to do more than just add so I do need to be able to see the jquery still from the foreach loop

Comment: I think what you need is not to see the jquery from the view but rather build some information that you can send down to client so it can be consumed in js/jquery. Better edit you question and give a more specific example. There can be many ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your add function and variable declaration outside of doc ready. The functions in doc ready are not available until your razor has executed.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  I have tried it in and out of document.ready and have adjusted the question to take code outside this as only moved inside it to test